# Phonograph query: how to join 2 datasets and get distinct

Tags: foundry-slate, foundry-phonograph

> My question concerns Slate + Phonograph end point. Solution can be expressed using ontology and objects creation but my business domain doesn't have permission to use them so I prefer to discuss about Slate + Phonograph.

My questions are at the end, first let me explain the context simplified like this:

1. I sync to foundry the database of a "tickets and actions management system" and I get 2 datasets:

   - one for TICKETS `primary key = ticket_number`
   - the other for TICKET'S ACTIONS `primary key = action_number, secondary key = ticket_number`
2. In a Slate application, user can observe charts and higlights about TICKETS and ACTIONS filtered on creteria relative to TICKETS' properties and ACTIONS' properties. For instance let's says displaying **count of `opened` Actions allocated to an `urgent` Ticket `opened last year`**.

To achive that I have 2 solutions:

1. perform 2 successive phonograph queries:

   - 1st. query on TICKETS filtered on "Urgent Ticket opened last year" => return TICKET NUMBERS
   - 2nd query on ACTIONS filter on TICKET NUMBERS of the previous query
   - (or in the reverse order: 1st ACTION, 2nd TICKET).
2. work with only 1 dataset which is already the "join" of TICKETS and ACTIONS.

My concerns and questions are:

- in the 1st solution I may be required to handle large quantity of TICKET NUMBERS (or ACTION NUMBERS) that exceed 10 000 numbers.

  - Q1: Is it good to ingest them in the second query?
  - Q2: what can I do when TICKET NUMBERS exceed 10 000 numbers?
  - Q3: is there a mean to join queries directely in the backend with phonograph like in SQL (SELECT * from TICKET LEFT JOIN ACTION WHERE x y z)?
- in the 2nd solution count and other KPIs of TICKET are not unique as soon as there is more than one action corresponding to the filter. I can clean the data with a JS function to keep only unique TICKETS but there is a blocking point if I want to display them in table with server-side paggination.

  - Q4: is there a mean to get distinct rows (doc) in phonograph considering only some columns (prop)? Let's says returning one row per TICKET event if several ACTIONS fit the filter.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi @GDF_kuma I'm hunting someone to answer this because I don't know the exact answer. I would like however to provide a tip on question making in stackoverflow. Each question in stackoverflow should be focused in only one thing, and even though your questions are related, you should aim at having each question as focused as possible, otherwise it may be closed down as "too vage", "needs more focus", etc... I would recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank youfor ypur interest and your tip. I thought first to split my concern in several post but I don't know how to present each point simply and at theend when I wrote the explanation I found that they are all linked to the same situation. Maybe my vocab is too limited and any help will be appreciated. Nethertheless I think my point is exposed and maybe someone hadthe same experience and can help me.

Comment: Hi @GDF_kuma you have higher chances to receive an answer if the question is more focused on one part of the whole complexity.